# get .json of twitterfall | twitter steam service

Tags: javascript, twitter

I do not know how to download a json with the latest tweets according to a particular search. How can I get them, or if there is a more reliable source to receive the latest tweets I would like to be advised.

https://twitterfall.com/

Answer (score 1):

Twitterfall uses the Twitter search API, which lets you retrieve a JSON of latest tweets according to a particular search. The documentation is available [in Twitter's Developer resources](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search).

You could also use something like [t](https://github.com/sferik/t) to get the results out as CSV, which might be suitable for your purposes?